# Divide a set of stones which weigh $1g, 2g, 3g....555g$ into $3$ equal parts

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I managed to prove it for $5, 6, 9$ and  $15$ sets of stones.

Is there some way to prove by induction that every number divisible by $3$ can be divided in this manner?

Comment: Are you sure it is true? $555$ is also a multiple of $3$.

Comment: Does the number of stones in each group have to be the same as well as the total weight of each group being equal. The fact you have done it for $5$ suggests that you are allowed $1+4, 2+3, 5$.

Comment: 3 is divisible by 3 but cannot be devided in 3 equal parts.

Comment: No... Number of stones need not be same

Comment: Can you do $8$? You should be able to show that if the number of stones is greater than $4$ and the total weight is divisible by $3$ then the stones can be split into three piles of equal weight.

Answer (score 5):

HINT: Can you see how to obtain a solution for $n+6$ from a solution for $n$?